# Laravel 4 password reset issue?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am getting an issues in password reset, which is difficult to debug for me.

[image]

I think it internally uses Blade template file which is in the following path
**app\views\emails\auth** and here is the code of it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
        <!--<h1>Hi {{$Name}}</h1>-->
        <2>Welcome</h2>

    <div>
            <p>We'd like to personally ........................!</p>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my password control:

```
<?php


class PasswordController extends  BaseController {

    public function remind()
    {
        return View::make('password.remind');
    }

    public function request()
    {
        $credentials = array('email' => Input::get('email'));

        return Password::remind($credentials);
    }

    public function reset($token)
    {
        return View::make('password.reset')->with('token', $token);
    }

}
```

Please let me know what is the issue.

Thanks all

Answer (score 1):

You're commenting php code using HTML comment tags.

Either delete the line or add blade comments:

{{-- This is a comment --}}

{{--

```
This is a
multi-line
comment.
```

--}}

Answer (score 1):

The `$name` given below is not commented in `Blade` template:

```
<!--<h1>Hi {{$Name}}</h1>-->
```

This is commented according to [Laravel Blade Templating Engine](http://laravel.com/docs/templates#other-blade-control-structures):

```
<!--<h1>Hi {{-- $Name --}}</h1>-->
```